# Request.IsAuthenticated is failed on server?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

`Request.IsAuthenticated` condition failed on server after I deploy the code. It is working for me when I ran from local server.

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("user", True)
Session("user") = mUser
Response.Redirect("~\Clients.aspx")
```

I am checking

```
Request.IsAuthenticated
```

in Clients.aspx page load. There it is failing.

How can I work it on server also ?.

Comment: How is it being used?  In what way did it fail?  A code snippet may be helpful here.

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug the issue? What kind of authentication is being used? Right now your question does not provide enough detail.

Comment: Very difficult to diagnose without more detail... What authentication method is configured on your development server, and how about the prod server? Posting the relevant section of your web.config file would help. Of course, anonymize it first...

Comment: give some credits to the people that answer your questions and start voting and accept answers

Comment: Is it failing all the time, or only some of the time? Are you in a web farm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on web.config the parameter **requireSSL="true"** on the **Authentication|forms** area.

If this option set to true, or not exist and the default is true, **then the Request.IsAuthenticated is fail if the pages you ask for is not encrypted with SSL.** (in other words if your pages are http:// and not https://)